# How do we disable frames to view the content in <noframes> tag in the same browser

Tags: html

I wanted to disable frames of a web page so that i can view the text equivalent that is mentioned in the  section.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the answer you likely want to hear, but you should **really, really** re-consider using frames.

Frames cause all kinds of issues that you very likely can avoid since almost all site/apps don't need them.

- frame content can not easily be bookmarked
- floating widgets, menus etc. will not float over frame boundaries
- you end up adding overhead HTTP requests (1 HTML for the frameset, 1 HTML each for each frame, 1 each for every CSS, JS, or SWF file loaded in each frame, etc.)
- keyboard tab navigation flows through an entire frame before jumping to the next frame (which limits your ability to set a simple logical flow sometimes)
- zooming in IE7/IE8 in frames causes all kinds of rendering glitches
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about deleting your frameset and putting your noframe content into the body tag ?